# How to implement lazy load on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application module that serves log data to the user. The MVC page has a filter that retrieves data via Ajax on filter selection which has values like 1 Week, 2 Week, 3 Week etc.

This is my function that serves the log

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetLogs(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var logs = applicationService.GetAllLogs(startDate, endDate).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
    return PartialView(logs);
}
```

This is my partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<ApplicationLogObj>
<table style="width:100%">
@foreach (var log in Model)
{
    <text>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <em>@log.DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") &nbsp;</em>
        </td>
        <td>
            @log.UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @log.Action on @log.Module 
        </td>

    </tr>       
    </text>
}
</table>
```

and the following is the jquery function I am running to show the log on the main page.

```
$(function () {

  $("#btn1Week").click(function () {

    var start = '@DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")';
    var end = '@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")';
    getLogs(start, end);
  });
  $("#btn2Week").click(function () {

    var start = '@DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")';
    var end = '@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")';
    getLogs(start, end);
  });
  $("#btn3Week").click(function () {

    var start = '@DateTime.Now.AddDays(-21).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")';
    var end = '@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")';
    getLogs(start, end);
  });

  function getLogs(start, end) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/AppLogs/GetLogs",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: { startDate:start, endDate:end },
      contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (result) {
        $("#logDiv").html(result);
      }
    });

    }

});
```

The application is running fine, but the problem is that the log consists of over 500 records just for a week. So when the user clicks on say 3 weeks, it takes a lot of time for the HTML to be parsed and served to the main application and sometimes the script goes in not responsive mode prompting the user to stop script.

Is there a simple way to implement what is known as 'lazy load' so that I can serve the log as the user scrolls down the screen (much like it happens in Google image search)?

Will appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you should be implementing paging or using a virtual scrolling plugin

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I do that

Comment: There are plenty of plugins that allow you do do this. Search [mvc paging](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+paging&oq=mvc+paging&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.2950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) or [mvc virtual scrolling](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+paging&oq=mvc+paging&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.2950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc+virtual+scrolling)

Comment: I saw this plugin called the jScroll (http://jscroll.com/) and it seems pretty neat to me, but I don't know how to hook it up with my ajax method which will page the log results.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you check out the documentation, search for any tutorials, demos etc. and if your still having problems, ask a new question with the code you have tried

Comment: @progrAmmar - It's important to actually understand the problem you're having before looking for a solution (something the other commenter jumped over).  Your problem seems to be a result of having so many records your HTML response ends up being enormous; this then puts a lot of weight on the browser while it updates the page.  You don't *need* Javascript to solve the problem, but it's certainly an option.  You could also solve this issue on the server with paging: http://goo.gl/TIgmH2

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Thank you, I know paging but we want to display the logs through infinite scrolling.

I implemented the jScroll and used paging to update the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was jScroll (http://jscroll.com/#examples). It serves the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this project:
   https://github.com/boylegu/vue-lazyload-text
The high performance magic text with lazyload support.