# I want a loader on my Loop so the product is coming from database load with the help of loader

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want a loader on my loop there are number of product are coming from data base i want they are load when the we scroll down any body can help me ? 
here is the code of loop :-
Any body can help me for implement loader on my loop or div ?

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="div-to-update">
        <div class="row leftcontent">
            <h4 class="hotdeal">Today's Hottest Deals</h4>
        </div>

        @foreach (var item in Model.DBDeals)
        {
                                  <div class="row leftimages" id="__AjaxLoader">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 innerimage">
                                        <a href="@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DealUrl)).Replace("&amp;", "&"))" target="_blank"><img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)" class="img-responsive1"> </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                            <h4 class="tag">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h4>
                                            <h5 class="greentext">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VendorName)</h5>
                                            <h5 class="freeship"></h5>
                                            @{ if (item.OfferPrice.HasValue)
                                             {
                                                <h5 class="freeship">Discount: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discount) %</h5>
                                                <h4 class="price">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfferPrice)  <span class="oldprice"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalPrice) <img src="~/images/blackline.png" class="blackline"></span></h4>
                                             }
                                            }
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p class="paragraph"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDescription)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row blackstrip">
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                                        <h5 class="lefticons"><img src="~/images/like.png"><a href="#">Like</a></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3 icon">
                                        <h5 class="lefticons"><img src="~/images/share.png"><a href="#">Share</a></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3 icon">
                                        <h5 class="lefticons"><img src="~/images/more.png"><a href="#">More</a></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-md-offset-3 buy">
                                        <h4 class="buynow"><a href="@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DealUrl)).Replace("&amp;", "&"))" target="_blank">Buy Now</a></h4>
                                    </div>
                    </div>        

        }


    </div>
```

Comment: Please note that [tag:model-view-controller] is meant for questions about the *pattern*, whereas your question concerns the ASP.NET implementation of said pattern. I've adjusted your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a loading div before entering the loop and then hide it on loop exit

```
 <div class="loader">
         Loading.....
 </div>
@foreach (var item in Model.DBDeals)
 {
.
.
.
}
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".loader").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: i want my product load when i scroll down my page ?

Comment: I suppose what you are trying to ask is to implement lazy load. Which means your products load as you scroll down the page.

You cannot achieve this by performing foreach in the razor page as it will serve you all the products. I implemented lazy load on my text. Check my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401444/how-to-implement-lazy-load-on-text

Comment: can i do loading with the help of ajax? i want my product is load when i scrolled down the page ?

Comment: Yes you can do loading with ajax.

Comment: when i scroll down my product is loading i want that kind of functionality i have record coming on foreach loop please help me how can i implement loading when i scroll down my scroll-er?